# Scikit-learn’s implementation of Dirichlet Process Gaussian Mixture Model: Gibbs sampling or Variational inference?

Tags: scikit-learn

Reading the [docs of scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.sourceforge.net/dev/modules/mixture.html#dpgmm-classifier-infinite-gaussian-mixtures) I had understood that the implementation behind the DPGMM class use variational inference rather than the also traditional Gibbs sampling.

Nevertheless, while going through [this Edwin Chen's popular post](http://blog.echen.me/2012/03/20/infinite-mixture-models-with-nonparametric-bayes-and-the-dirichlet-process/) ("Infinite Mixture Models with Nonparametric Bayes and the Dirichlet Process") he says he uses scikit-learn to run *Gibbs sampling* inference of a DPGMM.

So, is there a Gibbs Sampling implementation of the DP-GMM in scikit-learn, Chen got it wrong or there *was* a Gibbs version that was replaced by the variational one?

Comment: I don't think there ever was a Gibbs sampling implementation.

Comment: I think you are right... Please, post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there never was a Gibbs sampling implementation. (And I have been with the project for a couple of years)